# SQL select based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

We have a DB table that contains company job codes like so:

```
ID       Code       Company
1        EW10       ***
2        EW10       DEU
3        EW10       DEC
4        EW20       ***
5        EW30       DEU
6        EW40       DEC
```

The '***' in company represents an enterprise level job code which can be overwritten at the employer level (DEU, DEC).

I need a select statement that returns rows with the following conditions:

- If there are no company specific Codes (e.g., EW20) then return the
  enterprise level row (e.g., row 4)
- If there are company specific rows, return all company specific rows

The result set I need would be the following:

```
ID       Code       Company
2        EW10       DEU
3        EW10       DEC
4        EW20       ***
5        EW30       DEU
6        EW40       DEC
```

Comment: You need to post your attempt too.

Comment: @BrianKE . . . I don't get what you want to do.  Why is row 1 filtered out?  You say you want to return all rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't say I want all rows returned.  I want the Enterprise level code returned unless there is a Company specific row.  If there is a Company specific row then return that.  This is why row 1 does not exist in the result set, the company specific codes override the enterprise level code.

Comment: @BrianKE . . . `code` is a column, not a row.  I interpreted the question as a transformation of that column.  You actually want to filter the rows, so you don't want all of them.  The phrasing is ambiguous, although somewhat clarified by the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can do this using an OR for the two scenarios:

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable yt1
WHERE  Company <> '***'
   OR  NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM YourTable yt2
          WHERE yt2.Code = yt1.Code AND yt2.Company <> '***'
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions.  This is slightly more complicated than necessary, because `***` is being used rather than `NULL`.  The following converts back and forth to `NULL`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(nullif(company, '***'),
                max(nullif(company, '***')) over (partition by code),
                '***'
               )
from t;
```

EDIT:

Your question says that you want to return *all* rows.  However, your sample data is otherwise.

I think you might want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.company <> '***' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and
                        t2.company <> '***'
                 );
```

Or, with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when company <> '***' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by code) as num_notstars
      from t
     ) t
where (num_notstars > 0 and company <> '***') or
      (num_notstarts = 0);
```

Comment: This does not work:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e06ee2d00a22aad415dbb375fe225618 but someone upvoted it!

Answer (score 1):

With UNION ALL for the 2 cases:

```
select * from tablename
where Company <> '***'
union all
select * from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where Code = t.Code and Company <> '***'
)
order by Id
```

Or:

```
select * from tablename
where Company <> '***'
or Code in (
  select Code from tablename
  group by Code
  having min(Company) = '***' and max(Company) = '***'
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee1c5f22faacce7d1227b722e9ea305f).
Results:

```
> ID | Code | Company
> -: | :--- | :------
>  2 | EW10 | DEU    
>  3 | EW10 | DEC    
>  4 | EW20 | ***    
>  5 | EW30 | DEU    
>  6 | EW40 | DEC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Select ID,Code,Company
 From  (
        Select *
              ,RN  = row_number() over (partition by [Code] order by [Company] desc) 
         From YourTable
       ) A
 Where (Company<>'***' and RN=1)
    or RN>1
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Code    Company
2   EW10    DEU
3   EW10    DEC
4   EW20    ***
5   EW30    DEU
6   EW40    DEC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, Code, Company
FROM table main
WHERE
(
    main. Company = '***'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT code
        FROM table sub
        WHERE main.code = sub.code
        AND main.id != sub.id
    )
) OR company != '***'
```

Hope that'll work for your needs! :)

Answer (score 0):

**This will work for you.**

```
Select * from tablename Where Company <> '***' 
UNION 
Select * from tablename  Where Code Not In ( Select Code from #Sejaltable Where Company <> '***')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to rank the rows; a company level row wins over an enterprise level row. Use `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` for this.

If you are looking for one particular company you'd rank your rows thus:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    mytable.*,
    row_number() over (partition by code
                       order by case when company = '***' then 2 else 1 end) as rnk
  from mytable
  where company in ('DEC', '***')
) ranked
where rnk = 1
order by code;
```

For all companies, I'd suggest to select the companies first and then join their matches:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    c.company, m.id, m.code, m.company as setting_company,
    row_number() over (partition by c.company, m.code
                       order by case when m.company = '***' then 2 else 1 end) as rnk
  from (select distinct company from mytable where company <> '***') c
  left join mytable m on m.company = c.company or m.company = '***'
) results
where rnk = 1
order by company, code;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd8dd25c81f35f91043dcf0a0a1743c9 . (This demo also contains an alternative way of writing the queries.)